# Laravel "Class not found..." when running artisan commands (but not composer)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an app I've been working on for a few weeks; I'm using Vagrant+Homestead for local development, and Forge+Linode for a staging environment; until a few days ago, my workflow was working fine, however  now when the deployment script runs in Forge (in particular `composer install`), it gets an error:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Reputationhub\ReputationhubServiceProvider' not found in /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhu
  b/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/artisan:0
  PHP   2. require_once() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/artisan:30
  PHP   3. require() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/bootstrap/start.php:60
  PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumin
  ate/Foundation/start.php:210
  PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/vendor/laravel/framework/
  src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:57
  PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/vagrant/Sites/reputationhub/vendor/laravel/framework/s
  rc/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:121
```

It is actually the subcommand `php artisan clear-compiled` that composer runs afterward that is failing.  If I run that on it's own, same problem.  Running `composer install --no-script` runs ok.
When I look at `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, it's missing all sorts of things, and is only a few lines long (it's normally much larger), so whatever Laravel is doing is not properly finding the correct classes.

The odd thing is that running `composer dump-autoload -o` seems to fix it; the `autoload_classmap.php` file finds everything, and the app runs fine, until `php artisan ...` tries to do anything, then it breaks the app.

The end result is that the Forge deployment is broken; I can manually jump onto the server and run `composer dump-autoload -o` to fix it, but that seems wrong.

I think I've been rather thorough about researching solutions, but so far I can't find anything, so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE: further clarification**

This is Laravel 4.2.

My `composer.json` autoload section looks like this:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Reputationhub\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": []
},
...
```

The provider has been added to the "providers" array in `app.php` like this:

```
...
'Reputationhub\ReputationhubServiceProvider',
...
```

And my provider file (at `app/Reputationhub/ReputationhubServiceProvider.php`) looks like this:

```
<?php namespace Reputationhub;

use Reputationhub\EventSubscribers\MetricsEventSubscriber;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ReputationhubServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

...

}
```

**Update 2: more testing**

Not sure what it does, but `composer install` seems to do something bad that breaks the app.  To fix it, rather than using `composer install` in the deployment script (which will subsequently call `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`, both of which will throw errors), if I use this it will repair itself:

```
...
composer install --no-scripts
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan dump-autoload
...
```

Comment: These problems seem to always come down to byte-code caching

Comment: Phil: You mean with apc or opcache or something?

Comment: Neither of those is turned on unfortunately.

Comment: About your update, artisan gives "`Command "dump-autoload" is not defined.`"